# Algorithm Efficiency; Growth Function and Big-O Representation

Tags: algorithm

So here's the algorithm:

```
Algorithm pow (a, n):
Input: two integers, a (base) and n (exponent)
Output: returns the equivalent of a^n

K ←  n
b ←  1
c ←  a

while k > 0 do
    if k mod 2 = 0 then
        k ←  k / 2
        c ← c * c
    else
        k ←  k − 1
        b ← b * c
return b
```

The exact growth function I'm not sure of, but it looks like log(n) + C; where C = the number of times that 'else' branch is executed. Any help here would be awesome! I've racking my head over this for too long to be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like homework so i'll keep my answer brief.

I think you should try show that the else branch is entered less than or equal to the other branch (everytime you have an odd number k and subtract one from it , you get an even number). And then show that the first branch is log(n), and so the second branch must be less than or equal to log(n), and 2*log(n) is also log(n)...

Comment: Thank you, I was just thinking about it too hard... Much appreciated!